# Why do I get a KFunction1 instead of List<E> in my RX chain?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

In my mapping method I'm trying to remap my `DTO` objects from the API into `VO` objects that I will use on the UI.

```
private fun dtoToVo(dto: List<AbwEANDTO>): List<AbwEANVO> {
        return List(dto.size) {
            AbwEANVO(dto[it].key, dto[it].text, false)
        }
    }
```

and I'm adding this method in my RX chain like this:

```
    override fun getDeviationLookupTable(test: Boolean) {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            api.getDeviationLookupTable(test)
                .map { ::dtoToVo }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    liveData.value = it
                }, {
                    Log.d(null, "Error@getDeviationLookupTable")
                })
        )
    }
```

I expect getting a `List<AbwEANVO>` inside `it`, but Kotlin tells me than a `KFunction1<@ParameterName List<AbwEANDTO>, List<AbwEANVO>>!` was found instead. It's a typical type mismatch error, but I really can't explain to myself why I'm getting it.

Please explain me what am I missing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `map` call, you're passing in a lambda by using curly braces `{}`, which takes the incoming parameter, ignores it, and returns a function reference. It's the same as writing down this code there:

```
.map { it -> ::dtoToVo }
```

So you're getting a stream of function references from that point down, which shows up as a `KFunction` when you subscribe to it at the end.

To pass in the function reference correctly, use regular parentheses:

```
.map(::dtoToVo)
```

This will call the `dtoToVo` function for each element, and continue the stream with whatever that function returns. So this is the equivalent of:

```
.map { it -> dtoToVo(it) }
```

Comment: I have to admit that I have somehow missed this out, because I was trying something different before it. You provided a great explanation to my issue. I will keep this in mind. Thank you so much.